# Enable OpenCL with Magick.NET

Tags: c#, .net, imagemagick, opencl, magick.net

I am using Magick.NET to despeckle an image. It take ~1-2 second for a relatively small image (1000*1500 pixels). I read that ImageMagick uses OpenCL to speed up some operations and despeckle is one of them. So, I wonder why it is so slow with a quite recent graphic card (GTX 960).

Is there a Magick.NET setting to enable OpenCL?

Comment: There is a mention of it on this page: https://magick.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Magick.NET.Web under Advanced configuration.

Answer (score 6):

You can enable or disable OpenCL by setting `OpenCL.IsEnabled`. The first time you use an OpenCL operation a benchmark will run to determine if it is better to use the GPU or the CPU. The benchmark is written inside the following file: `%LOCALAPPDATA%\ImageMagick\ImagemagickOpenCLDeviceProfile.xml`. An example of this benchmark is:

```
<devices>
  <device name="CPU" score="4.914"/>
  <device platform="AMD Accelerated Parallel Processing" score="0.165" vendor="Advanced Micro Devices, Inc." name="Ellesmere" version="2117.14 (VM)" maxClockFrequency="1266" maxComputeUnits="36" />
  <device platform="AMD Accelerated Parallel Processing" score="1.326" vendor="Advanced Micro Devices, Inc." name="Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4790K CPU @ 4.00GHz" version="2117.14 (sse2,avx)" maxClockFrequency="3998" maxComputeUnits="8" />
</devices>
```

The device with the lowest score wins and will be used when it is possible to use OpenCL inside an algorithm.

It is possible that the benchmark already ran on your machine and decided that the CPU is faster. This means that even though OpenCL is enabled the CPU will be used.

Comment: I tried `OpenCL.IsEnabled = true` but it take exactly the same time as with a `false` value. I checked `%LOCALAPPDATA%\ImageMagick\ImagemagickOpenCLDeviceProfile.xml`, I have 2 entries, the CPU and the GPU with the respective scores of 20.07 and 0.2197, so the GPU should be chosen. When I debug, I check the GPU usage with `MSI Afterburner` and it stay at 1-2 % while the CPU clearly take the load. So, I wonder where could be the problem.

Comment: The current implementation of AccelerateDespeckleImage requires a RGBA image and does not work with a RGB image. I need to modify the OpenCL kernel to add support for that.

Comment: `AccelerateDespeckleImage` is the method of ImageMagick you use, right? I tried to change `MagickReadSettings.ColorSpace`, but there is no `RGBA` entry in the enum. When do you think that would be supported (I'm not squeezing you, just to know)?

Comment: You prob need to enable the alpha channel with `image.HasAlpha=true`.

Comment: There is still no changes. I ended up making my own pixel shaders and applying them using the `Effect` property of the WPF image component.